# Error: Uncaught [TypeError:default is not a constructor] jest mock

Tags: javascript, typescript, jest-mock-axios, jest-mock-extended

I have a service class FooService.js which I'm using in my component

```
export default class FooService {
  saveInfo = (params) => {
    //method implementation here.
  };
}
```

I'm using this in my component Foo.tsx  in saveData method as below:

```
const saveData = (message: string) => {
    const fooService = new FooService();
    fooService.saveInfo(params);
  };
```

I'm trying to mock my FooService as below in Foo.test.tsx

```
jest.mock('src/js/services/FooService', () => {
  return {
    _esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        saveInfo: jest.fn(),
      };
    }),
  };
```

When I run my test case from Foo.test.tsx file in debug mode,  I'm able to get inside saveData method. But, when I hit `const fooService = new FooService();` line, it throws the following error: **TypeError: FooService_1.default is not a constructor**

Please let me know what is that I'm missing in jest.mock. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show how are you importing the FooService in Foo.tsx

Comment: import FooService from 'src/js/services/FooService';

Answer (score 1):

Replacing _esModules with __esModules solved the issue.